# Java Separators

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jframe, windowbuilder

I was just wondering how to make a frame using the Eclipse Windows Builder. The separator I mean is the one where you can enter different column and the user can re-size them and you can place information in them. Like the one in the image below.

[image]

Comment: How do I add an element to the table?

Comment: Here you have a official tutorial [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Any tutorials on using windows builder to do this? Like add columns?

Comment: Never use window builder i dont even what is it. but you sure can find in google!